# How to create a pop up message with Amazon Cognito when using their hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am currently using Amazon Cognito as the OAuth2.0 server for Google home.

I am using the hosted UI for Sign-in and Sign-up.

It seems like the hosted UI, other than the logo and CSS, has very little customizable interface.

Is it possible to have a pop up message, just after the Sign-in process, for the user to agree to the terms and conditions?

I tried using Lambda for this but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Are there any other solutions to this without creating a brand new UI?

Thanks a lot!